# Flash cs6 - Actionscript 3: use input txt to change dynamic txt

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textinput

I have two fields, one text input field named: txtInn and I have a text output field (dynamic text field) named txtUt

I don't get any errors but nothing happens.

**Here is my code**

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stage.focus = txtInn;

txtInn.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handler);
function handler(event:KeyboardEvent){

   if(event.charCode === 13){
        txtUt.text = "You wrote: " + txtInn.text;
  }
}
```

[image]

**Download .fla** [HERE](https://mega.nz/#!WIwChaqB!GkiwEtead3V4ejOsenfoOsFVdO8uY-GUjvLZxgP1tVQ)

Comment: Your code looks good. When I click Enter I see ”You wrote: some text” in the txtUt. Try to check text color and text antialiasing (try to change to Use defaults fonts). Can you upload your FLA file?

Comment: adding to what subdan said, just add a trace(event.charCode) inside your event listener and at least confirm you are getting the event.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AndrewSellenrick I do get a return but still no change in the dynamic text (txtUt)

Comment: I tried fiddling around with fonts and embeeding but unfortunately with no luck @subdan Uppload link added + it's here [link](https://mega.nz/#!WIwChaqB!GkiwEtead3V4ejOsenfoOsFVdO8uY-GUjvLZxgP1tVQ)

Comment: @stanley The text color of the txtUt is white! Change to black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change text color of the `txtUt` from white to black.

**UPDATE**

Change `txtInn` behaviour to `Single line` in the Properties panel.

Comment: Tried doing that but only the "You wrote: " text came up :/

Comment: When you press enter a new line of text add to the txtInn. To prevent this read update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok in 1 of my project i use event handler and it working fine for . hope it will also work for you.

```
txtInn.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, TextChanged);

function TextChanged(e:Event):void{

    txtOut.text = "your text"+txtInn.txt;
}
```

Comment: I set the textInn.text when the .swf file is playing

Comment: Okay so I discovered my problem. The txtOut/txtUt will automatically add a new line so my box was to small. So when i made the box wider I was able to see the txt: **IMAGE** [link](http://i.imgur.com/sfiTMy5.png?1)